# Welcome message in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm programming a discord bot and I'm having a problem in one of the main functionalities - the welcome message.
I've tried several methods but none of them worked, except for one: `the one that needs a channel ID`.

I dont want to use that method because I want to use my bot on multiple servers, and that would mean that I have to change the code for each one of them - and I really dont want to.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', function(message) {
 member.guild.channels.cache.get('MY CHANNEL ID').send('welcome dadadadada');
});
```

This code worked (actually, I just tried it and it doesn't - but it did. It was something like that). Now I'm trying more 'advanced' coding to tell the bot to automatically get the channel ID from #general (for this I did `npm install long`)

```
const getDefaultChannel = (guild) => {

  if(guild.channel.has(guild.id))
    return guild.channels.get(guild.id)

    const generalChannel = guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'general');
    if (generalChannel)
      return generalChannel;
    return guild.channels
      .filter(c => c.type === 'text' &&
      c.permissionsFor(guild.client.user).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))
    .sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position) ||
      Long.fromString(a.id).sub(Long.fromString(b.id)).toNumber()
    .first();
}

client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {

  const channel = getDefaultChannel(member.guild);

  channel.send(`Welcome ${member} to the server, wooh!`);
});
```

I didn't find anything useful and I don't know what to do. Also, english is not my first language.

What else could I try? Thank you.

Comment: if I understood this correctly you want to send the welcome message into a channel of the guild. The guild object has something called `systemChannelID`. Thats the channel you get the discord welcome messages, "Hey there, we hope you brought pizza" etc, in.

Comment: Are you using v11.x? And are you getting any errors with your current method? What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca I'll see what I can do with that information, thank you

Comment: @Lioness100 I got a "can't read property -- of undefined" type of error (I'll edit the question and add the error), but I was looking for a way of doing it, not a fix to an error because that code doesn't work for me, but anyways, thank you for replying too
(it's very possible that i misspelled something or said something wrong, my apologies)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you!

*The guildMemberAdd listener can send messages*

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', function(member, message) => {
  let generalChannelName = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'general');
  let generalChannel = generalChannel.id;

  generalChannel.send(`Welcome ${member.tag} to the server!`);
});
```

It's hard to insert your filtering here, may this help you?

Comment: According to the discord.js docs, the guildMemberAdd event has no parameter message. Are you sure this would work? [https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd]